# Is there an alternative for checking range.Find() that is concise as `If not range is nothing then`?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

Background:

When verifying that a range was found via `range.find()`, I have historically used something like:

```
Dim foundRange as Range:  Set foundRange = sheets(1).usedrange.find("moo")
If Not foundRange is Nothing then debug.print foundRange.address
```

Having never really deviated from this, nor put too much extra thought into it, to date, I guess it might as well be time to challenge what I know/use.

---

Inquiry:

Is there any inherent equivalent to this check that does not require the `Not` modifier nor a UDF (e.g., `Exists(range)` which still uses the `Not` modifier or does a check via `dictionary`)?

I would suspect that `if not range is nothing` is about as concise as one can be, but here we are to have the conversation.

Comment: That's about as concise as it gets.

Comment: If you're really anti `not` there's nothing stopping you in VBA from having an empty `If` block and jumping right to `Else` though I'd argue that looks sloppier than a negation, and of course won't work with a single line `If`

Comment: @BigBen thanks for confirming

Comment: @Warcupine i wouldn't say "anti-`not`" as much as wondering... and i'm very much not about that look with the else condition only, part of why my sample code is in-line.  Thanks for chiming in!